# Copy Range Excluding Blank Cells - Paste to Another Sheet

Tags: vba, copy, pivot

Ok, back again!

I have tried to search throught this and other forums to find a similar solution, but everything Ive found is either just different enough that I cant figure out the application to my problem, or super complex, and I cant translate it! So Im hoping someone can help me here. Thanks in advance!!

Here is the scenario. I have a database that Im needing to add data to. Quote Number, PO Number,SubSystem Part Name, Vendor, Material, Price, Qty. Etc.

Long story short, and without getting into the context of why I did it this way (mostly because I think I would botch the explaination and be more confusing than helpful!) ... I have essentially 3 tables right next to each other.

Table 1 is columns H and I. These all have a formula similar to =if(isblank(J4),"",$I$1) Where I1 is the PO Number (which will remain the same for this set of entries.)
Table 2 is a pivot table in columns J through M. Using a slicer the user can select what sub systems they need for this PO. The pivot table will repopulate with the appropriate part numbers and unique information contained in another table. 
Table 3 is a regular table in columns N through R. These columns have some formulas like above that pull from a single cell (for entering the date), some pull information from another table based on information in column J via a VLOOKUP, and some information is entered manually.

That might be too much information, but better to have it and not need it eh?

So heres the goal. With a VBA macro, I want to copy the data and paste it onto another sheet, at the bottom of a database. The trick is, because that whole setup above runs based on information coming from a pivot table, the list changes length constantly. It will never be longer than a certain length (still TBD) but will almost always be shorter. I can copy the whole thing, and have it paste to another sheet below the last entry... but it pastes below the last empty cell in the database sheet. What I mean is this:

The longest the table could be would be range H4:R38 for example. So I copy that, paste it to Sheet2 starting at cell A2. Upon further inspection, we see that there is only actual data in the range H4:R11. However, when we pasted it to Sheet2 it pasted the whole range H4:R38. When I run the macro again, instead of the new data set being pasted to row A10 (the row after where the data should have ended), it pastes to something like row 36... because its pasting below all the blank cells.

I have no idea what to do or where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Code I've Tried:

```
Dim fabricationrange As Range
Dim destination As Range
Dim LastBBUFabDatabaseRow As Long

Worksheets("Sub Systems").Range("h4:r38").Copy

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BBU Fab. Database")

Worksheets("bbu fab. database").Range("z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats


    lastbbufabdatabserow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row = 1
    Set destination = .Cells(LastBBUFabDatabaseRow, 2)

   destination.Value = PasteSpecial.Values

End With
```

Comment: FYI "wall of text" questions typically do not fare well here.  Most folks here are interested in seeing your *code*, along with a description of the exact problem you're having with it.  If you only post the description, but not the code, we can only guess what changes you need to make.

Comment: Thats just it Tim, I dont have a start point, or know where to begin with the code. I would post what I have....if I had anything.

Comment: In addition to that...the reason for the "wall of text" was because, in my attempted reserach, I found a case where formulas were included in "blank" cells and that screwed with the results. Not trying to over explain, just trying to give as much information as possible.

Comment: If the main problem is finding the last row of your data then maybe start here:  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba  It's fine to include relevant details, but also including even a small section of code you're tried (even if it doesn't work) usually helps people give you suggestions.  Reading code is typically easier and quicker if you want to get the intent, and looking at how code is structured can help us pitch the answer to match your existing code.

Comment: No, actually I have that part sorted... i think.

What im needing is how to copy the non blank cells, and exclude any cells that have formulas, but no value in the cell. that way I can paste only those to the next sheet. 

As far as what code, Ive looked at (and subsequently deleted) several, but the most recent is:

Comment: 'Dim fabricationrange As Range
'Dim destination As Range
'Dim LastBBUFabDatabaseRow As Long

'Worksheets("Sub Systems").Range("h4:r38").Copy

'With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BBU Fab. Database")

'Worksheets("bbu fab. database").Range("z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


'Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats


    'lastbbufabdatabserow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row = 1
    'Set destination = .Cells(LastBBUFabDatabaseRow, 2)

   ' destination.Value = PasteSpecial.Values

Comment: You can edit your question to add code - more than one line is difficult to make out in a comment.

Comment: I have done as you asked! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Untested but here's a brute-force approach to locating the first empty row:

```
set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BBU Fab. Database").rows(2) '<< start here
do while application.counta(rngDest) > 0
    set rngDest = rngDest.offset(1, 0) 'next row
loop
Worksheets("Sub Systems").Range("H4:R38").Copy
rngDest.cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats '<< paste to col A
```